# Ethernet USB adapter NOT based on Realtek chip

Tags: usb, ethernet, intel

I would like to know if there exists any USB to Ethernet Adapter that is not based on Realtek chip. My budget is up to $100.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there are adapters based on **ASIX AX88179** chipset.

For example Ugreen RJ45 USB Adapter - https://www.ugreen.com/collections/usb-ethernet-adapter/products/usb-3-0-to-gigabit-rj45-ethernet-adapter.

IMPORTANT: Ugreen RJ45 **USB-C** Adapter is based on **Realtek**.

Answer (score 3):

https://plugable.com/products/usb2-e100   **USB2-E100**  based on **ASIX AX88772**

I've used this extensively in windows 7, 10, and linux under SLES 11.4 and RHEL/CentOS 7.x with no problems.

note this is an older product, possibly obsolete but can be found on amazon for $8-15 each.

pluggable website shows USB3-E1000, list price $20, using ASIX AX88179